# How can I calculate user's CPU usage percentage from React website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm trying to get the user's CPU usage percentage from a React application. I've tried using `os.loadavg()` ([documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_loadavg)), but this gives the load average, which is something else I believe. I've also tried using this program from someone in GitHub ([here](https://gist.github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/c40e1ebb9f709d091208e89baf9f4e00)), but it's very inconsistent and depending on where I run it, the values are different. For instance, if I run it on an IDE online, I get a certain value, but on another IDE its different as well.

**What I want is to get the actual user's average, not my website's usage or anything of the sort. The tool I'm creating is supposed to give information to the user about their own CPU usage.**

I'd appreciate if you could help, thanks.

Comment: unsure how you expect node to the the CPU of the user....

Comment: The browser javascript api doesn't have access to a lot of system information. It's kept in a sandbox to make sure it's safe to run. There are platforms such as node and electron that have more access to the system, but they are more complicated to set up.

Comment: @CharlesBamford so I should use Nodejs along with React to make this work? But how would I go about getting this information? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! My problem was wanting to use client side vs server side